# How to get lastest inserted record _id in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-web-server

I am trying to get recently inserted record _id and p_id but i do not know how to get the value.Below given my code.This is not working.How to do it?

DB records:

```
{
_id:5eba58f0e5def333ad4d8c8d,
p_id:"C1",
product_name:"Name",
product_weight:123
},
{
_id:5eba58f0e5def333ad4d8c8e,
p_id:"C2",
product_name:"Name",
product_weight:123
},
{
_id:5eba58f0e5def333ad4d8c8f,
p_id:"C3",
product_name:"Name",
product_weight:123
}
```

data.controller.js:

```
var Product = mongoose.model(collectionName);

 let latest_id = Product.findOne().sort({ field: 'asc', _id: -1 }).limit(1);

 console.log("_id" + val);  //output should be 3 

 let latest_p_id = Product.findOne().sort({ field: 'asc', p_id: -1 }).limit(1);

 console.log("p_id" + val);  //output should be C3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. MongoDB does not natively support incremental auto generated numbers, so your first case, it's not possible if you don't manage your counter separately. You can count the number of documents, but it won't account for deleted documents.
2. For the second case, you almost got it:

with async/await

```
const product = await Product.findOne().sort({ p_id: -1 }).limit(1)
console.log(product.p_id) // this will be your desired output
```

without async/await

```
Product.findOne().sort({ p_id: -1 }).limit(1).then((product) => {
  console.log(product.p_id) // this will be your desired output
})
```

Comment: Getting Error: SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function

Comment: I have added an alternative in the answer

Comment: p_id value getting null

Comment: Wow..Really great